# ApexCharts: how to modify tooltip formating

Tags: apexcharts

This is my first attempt at ApexCharts. I am actually running it from within ColdFusion.
Here is the code:

```
    tooltip: {
      shared: false,
      intersect: false,
      y: {
        formatter: function (y) {
          if(typeof y !== "undefined") {
            return  y.toFixed(0) + " points";
          }
          return y;
        }
      }
    }
```

When I look at the output, I see this tooltip:
[image]

I am looking for a way to remove word "points" in tooltip.
Also, is it possible to change area/line colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `formatter` ads this word in this line

```
return y.toFixed(0) + " points";
```

Just don't add string at the end

```
return y.toFixed(0);
```

And this is how you define colors array in options https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/

```
colors: ['#546E7A', ...]
```

You can also do it in `series`

```
series: [
  {
    name: "Series 1",
    data: [...],
    color: '#546E7A'
  },
  ...
],
```